# Getting file name and path from NSDirectoryEnumerator

Tags: objective-c, filenames, filepath

I want to know if there is any chance with a `NSDirectoryEnumerator` object to get the path of a file and the name of it.

At this moment to get the file name I need to do the following:

Being fileEnumerator a `NSDirectoryEnumerator`:

```
while ((file= [fileEnumerator nextObject]))...
```

But what I would like to do is to be able to get the fileName directly through `fileEnumerator`, without needing to use the `nextObject` function.

And I also would like to know if from `fileEnumerator` there could be any chance to get the folder of the main file.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks for the edition Unheilig, forgot to do it by myself

Comment: what is wrong with nextObject? this is how it enumerates directories, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Enumerator is created to enumerate the objects. This is some kind of access to more file/dictionaries. I don't realy understand your requirements. What are you trying to do? Maybe you shouldn't have use this enumerator at all.

Comment: What I want to do is to scan all the files in concrete folders. For this I am calling couple of functions (to structure well the code) and I have to send to one of this functions the parameter of fileName and filePath... I just though there was a chance to get the information from the enumerator instead of sending so many variables to the function